Android Studio Ladybug: Pairing Devices via Wi-Fi not working
I am trying to execute and debug a program that I am developing in Android Studio (version: Koala | 2024.1.1 Patch 1) on my physical mobile (a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra) via WiFi.
The paring (be it via QR-code or via pairing code) always ends in "Connecting to device. This takes up to 2 minutes" and after that time invariably fails with "an error occured connecting device. Scan to try again", i.e. I NEVER get a working connection.
I had this working a few months back with the precursor of Koala (Jellyfish). It also hadn't been very stable back then but typically after 2 or 3 attempts one got this working and once the connection was set up it worked OK. With Koala I have been completely out of luck so far. This is SO frustrating! Any ideas anyone what one could check and/or try to get this going?
I already rebooted my Laptop (MS Surface Pro 8) - didn't make a difference.
Later addition: (Nov. 2024) the same (or actually: much worse) hassle with Android Studio Ladybug (2024.2.1 Patch 1) again! I thus also changed the title of this post. This time its a real PITA! Not seldom does it take me half an hour or more (including restarts of Android Studio and even the entire Laptop) to get the devices to connect.
I disabled my devices' MAC randomization feature but that didn't seem to make any difference. Also, trying via command-line, didn't work any better. And all my devices have fixed IP-addresses, so changing addresses also can not be the reason for these connection issues.
I also noted that typically the QR-code gets grayed out after scanning it and the message that it is now connecting to the device and that this may take up to two minutes appears in Android Studio and on the device my "userId@deviceName" is shown as "paired device" at the bottom of the "Wireless debugging" dialog (so, at least some communication must have happened here) but then the rotating dots endlessly spin and eventually the laptop shows an error message that it could not connect. They really haven't got this baked, yet.
I am starting get really annoyed with this! It makes testing soooo tedious!  >:-(

use command line(1):
PS D:\path> adb pair 192.168.3.3:33333
Enter pairing code: 333333
error: protocol fault (couldn't read status message): No error

success(2):
PS D:\path> adb pair 192.168.3.3:33333 333333
Successfully paired to 192.168.3.3:33333 [guid=adb-WADWADSWDSDAWDSDWD]

In my pc ,after method 2 is successful, it seems that method 1 can also be used.

Thanks both (@卡尔斯路西法 and @gtxtreme) for responding and the advice. The command line version worked. Strange enough, after a while (a few weeks later) this was suddently working again from the application as well.
It even survived the upgrade to v2024.1.2 and is still working from the menu-entry "Pair Devices via WiFi" again. It also works flawless with my mobile as well as with my tablet. I hope, this remains so...

You can try the following for a Samsung phone

You can resolve the issue from within Wi-Fi settings by disabling the Randomized MAC Address feature under Privacy. Using the device's actual MAC address fixes the issue

You can also manually assign IP addresses to your device from your router, and disable DHCP


There are other options like using the command line to pair as well which can be found here
